# Using php mail() but email going in spam box

Tags: php, email

I am using this simple php mail() function to mail on gmail. But this email is going in spam box. please help me to solve this problem

```
<?php
$to = "delhisadarbazaar@gmail.com";
$subject = "HTML email";

$message = "
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML email</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>This email contains HTML Tags!</p>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>John</td>
<td>Doe</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
";
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: <raman.singh9718@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: raman.singh9718@gmail.com' . "\r\n";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

Comment: The subject of the mail might be an issue.  There are certain keywords being flagged by different mail service providers

Comment: Please check this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260910/php-email-how-to-avoid-mail-ending-up-in-spam-box