# How to configure .env file avoid spam mail in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, email, laravel-5.4

I am working with Laravel 5.4. When I am sending mail from Local server  mail is going to the inbox folder working fine, configure file **.env** following :-

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=email
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

After that I shift to live server and I configure the **.env** file following:->

```
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

mail receive but in spam folder.How to avoid from spam folder.

Here is my Controller  function

```
function createSchool(Request $request){

        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

        $user = $this->create($request->all());

        if($user){

            $mailInformation = $request->all();

            if($mailInformation){

                Mail::to($request->user())
                ->cc($mailInformation['email'])
                ->send(new SchoolRegistration($mailInformation)); 
            }

            return redirect('admin/schools')->with('success', 'School  added Successfully');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Whether or not something ends up in spam is not something your app can directly control. It depends on the email content and the recepients' settings. If you're sending to Gmail users then [Google has some guidelines](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6227174) you should be following

Comment: @apokryfos but same mail content and same recepients got mail in inbox when mail fire from localhost

Comment: Maybe localhost is a more trusted domain than whatever host it is you're using. If you're using a shared provider then someone else using the same provider to send spam will cause the same IPs to be blacklisted. Read the Google suggestions

Comment: @apokryfos ok Thank you so much

Answer (score 7):

Your emails landing is spam has nothing to do with the framework but there are a couple of things that you could check why it happens:

- Is the domain hosted on the server that is sending the email?
- Is a correct SPF record setup for my domain?
- Is my message source valid? Does it contain content that might trigger spam filters?
- Are the headers set properly?

These questions contribute to emails not landing in spam but it's not a definite solution. :-)

Some reading material:
[php email - how to avoid mail ending up in spam box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260910/php-email-how-to-avoid-mail-ending-up-in-spam-box)
[How do you make sure email you send programmatically is not automatically marked as spam?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371/how-do-you-make-sure-email-you-send-programmatically-is-not-automatically-marked?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably Reverse-DNS-Lookup. If you want to be sure that your emails arrive and are not marked as spam then you need to set up your own email server. I use sendmail on linux servers.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the main reason was markdown, I switched markdown to simple views and problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

use view insted of markdowm in your mail.php . it will solve your problem :)

Comment: For completeness, please explain why